# Post quantum signature scheme integration in Monero

Tags: monero-forks, quantum-computing, integration

I have a pretty ambitious experiment in mind, and more of it is like testing how would a crypto currency behave if it would have some post quantum keys, like 2KB of key sizes and signatures.

So I looked up on the top cryptocurrencies, which is highly respected in privacy, and I chose Monero. I also picked a random key generation scheme dilithium(https://pq-crystals.org/dilithium/index.shtml).

So on the coding, everything went quite well, on changing the sizes, and hash functions, but when I generated the wallet, I get this weirdly formatted address and key.

Can you help me what might the problem?

Result: https://pastebin.com/g3kFZNwP

Comment: I believe this is overly broad. Please break this into *specific* questions about key / address generation and encoding with actual code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mnemonic seed is a representation of your secret spend key. It looks like your secret key has a LOT of zero bytes.
There are 3 words for every 4 bytes, so if your secret keys are 2 kB, you end up with 1536 words. Abbey being the first word in the English dictionary, you see that the key you're encoding there is mostly zeroes.
The output format expects only 25 words, so inserts two newlines. The rest is on a single line.